# Migration K8S cluster

Tags: kubernetes, dns

we have several clusters. Right now, we want to upgrade a K8S cluster replacing it for new one.

We handle the deployments with CICD, so, when the new cluster is ready, we will start to move apps to the new cluster running the pipelines.
We're facing a problem with DNS.

All the apps in the kubernetes cluster is resolved by a wildcard DNS.
Besides, we need to do the migration in multiple steps, so, we can't change the wildcard to the new cluster, because the old cluster is going to host some apps for a while and need to interact between them

Any good solution or alternative to get the migration done smoothly?

And what would be a best practice about DNS to avoid this situation in the future?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put in specific DNS records for each hostname as they need to migrate.

Say your wildcard is for `*.mycompany.com`...
`app1.mycompany.com` is getting migrated
`app2.mycompany.com` is staying put until the next batch

Add a record for `app2.mycompany.com` pointing to the old cluster, and switch the wildcard record to point to the new cluster.

Now `app1.mycompany.com` will resolve to the new cluster, but the more specific record for `app2.mycompany.com` will trump the wildcard and keep pointing to the old cluster.

When it's time for `app2`'s DNS cutover, delete the record and the wildcard will take over.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I've thougth in two possibilities. One of them is what you point.. the another one is trusting in external-dns mechanism.
The dns more specific record solution seems to me too simple. So, I want to know what options are people using for their K8S clusters related to ingress DNS and if there is a common best practice.
but.. well, you know sometimes simpler is best.